# How to fix 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'get_figure' when plotting subplots

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I have written the following code to plot 6 pie charts in different subplots, but I get an error. This code works correctly if I use it to plot only 2 charts, but produces an an error for anything more than that.

I have 6 categorical variables in my dataset, the names of which are stored in the list `cat_cols`. The charts are to be plotted from the training data `train`.

**CODE**

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(2, 3, figsize=(24, 10))

for i, c in enumerate(cat_cols):
  
  train[c].value_counts()[::-1].plot(kind = 'pie', ax=axes[i], title=c, autopct='%.0f', fontsize=18)
  axes[i].set_ylabel('')
    
plt.tight_layout()
```

**ERROR**

```
AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'get_figure'
```

How do we rectify this?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

- The issue is `plt.subplots(2, 3, figsize=(24, 10))` creates two groups of 3 subplots, not one group of six subplots.

```
array([[<AxesSubplot:xlabel='radians'>, <AxesSubplot:xlabel='radians'>, <AxesSubplot:xlabel='radians'>],
       [<AxesSubplot:xlabel='radians'>, <AxesSubplot:xlabel='radians'>, <AxesSubplot:xlabel='radians'>]], dtype=object)
```

- Unpack all of the subplot arrays from `axes`, using `axes.ravel()`.

  - [`numpy.ravel`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ravel.html), which returns a flattened array.
  - A list comprehension will also work, `axe = [sub for x in axes for sub in x]`
  - In practical terms, [`axes.ravel()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ravel.html), [`axes.flat`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.flat.html), and [`axes.flatten()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.flatten.html), can be used similarly. See [What is the difference between flatten and ravel functions in numpy?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28930465/7758804) & [numpy difference between flat and ravel()](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38357811/7758804).
- Assign each plot to one of the subplots in `axe`.
- [How to resolve AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'get_figure' when plotting subplots](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64189469/) is a similar issue.

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# sinusoidal sample data
sample_length = range(1, 6+1)
rads = np.arange(0, 2*np.pi, 0.01)
data = np.array([np.sin(t*rads) for t in sample_length])
df = pd.DataFrame(data.T, index=pd.Series(rads.tolist(), name='radians'), columns=[f'freq: {i}x' for i in sample_length])

# crate the figure and axes
fig, axes = plt.subplots(2, 3, figsize=(24, 10))

# unpack all the axes subplots
axe = axes.ravel()

# assign the plot to each subplot in axe
for i, c in enumerate(df.columns):
    df[c].plot(ax=axe[i])
```

[image]