# How to iteratively plot to the correct subplot axes

Tags: pandas, matplotlib, seaborn, axis, subplot

Let's say I have two dataframes:

```
a = pd.DataFrame({"A": [2,3,4,5], 
                  "B": [4,8,9,10], 
                  "C" :[63,21,23,4],
                  "D": [56,32,12,2]
                 })

b = pd.DataFrame({"A": [12,13,14,15], 
                  "B": [41,81,91,10], 
                  "C": [3,2,5,6], 
                  "D": [4,2,3,4]
                 })
```

I want to be able to plot scatterplots between the variables on each dataframe with the same name. I've come up with the following code:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots((round(len(b)/2)),2,figsize=(10,10))
for i, col in enumerate(b.columns):

    sns.regplot(x=a[col], y=b[col], ax=ax[i,0])
    plt.title(col)
    sns.regplot(x=a[col], y=b[col], ax = ax[i,1])
    plt.title(col)


plt.tight_layout()
```

However, this yields the following figure:

[image]

What I want is:

[image]

I know this will be simple, but I just can't figure out a way of looping for the second ax[i,1].
Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `ax` is a `numpy` array, so it's easier to use [`.ravel`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ravel.html), which flattens the array and makes it easier to index

  - `ax`, in the OP, is a `(2, 2)` array, which `.ravel` flattens to `(4,)`.
- See the following SO questions for additional details regarding subplot axes arrays:

  - [How to fix 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'get_figure' when plotting subplots](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64229894/7758804)
  - [How to resolve AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'get_figure' when plotting subplots [duplicate]](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64189469/7758804)

```py
fig, ax = plt.subplots((round(len(b)/2)), 2,figsize=(10,10))
v = ax.ravel()
for i, col in enumerate(b.columns):

    sns.regplot(x=a[col], y=b[col], ax=v[i])
    v[i].set_xlabel(f'{col}_a')
    v[i].set_ylabel(f'{col}_b')
    v[i].set_title(col)

plt.tight_layout()
```

[image]